# How to update a record in Entity Framework using checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to update a record using EF. In my view I have used checkboxes to update multiple records. I have 2 problems
1)How to pass the edited textbox vales from view to controller and update those vales?
2)Every time when I edit something and update it is adding old data instead of updating the existing one.

View :

```html
@if (Model.Count > 0)
        {
            <div>
                @foreach (var books in Model)
                {
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => books.caption)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => books.caption)
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => books.copies)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => photos.copies)
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-1">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="@books.id" name="id" />
                        </div>
               }
          </div>
}

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="UPDATE" />
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="ADD"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="DELETE" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
public ActionResult EditBooks(int id, IEnumerable<int> id, string submitButton, [Bind(Include = "id,caption,copies")] Books books)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var item in id)
                {
                    var update = _db.Books.FirstOrDefault(s => s.id == item);

                    if (update != null)
                    {
                        _db.MyTable.Add(update);
                        _db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id});
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you are calling `MyTable.Add()`?

Answer (score 0):

According your logic you will add new record instead of updated. You can just analyze this bit of code:

```
_db.MyTable.Add(update);
```

According to entity framework logic you will put update item into **Add** EF action collection. So to fix it you need modify that bit of code to:

`_db.MyTable.Update(update);`